# Using stlplus library connect in wired network and do no connect in wireless

Tags: c++, tcp, network-programming, network-connection

all.

I use open source library stlplus for tcp-messaging.
The scheme of my work is next.

I have server application and client application. They can be both run and wait for other side to appear, then connect and exchange messages. Connection is created using server ip-address and port number.

In my wired local net everything works fine. Programs do not connect if only one is run (it seems obvious, but read further) and when connected exchange messages withou any problems.

After that I decided to test them in wireless net. So I created hosted network on one notebook and connected to it from another. Also i created homegroup of two computers. Ping (ip and port) between computers is ok. I even can send messages using windows's msg.exe.

And now is the problem.
Client program says (writes in log) that it connects to server and even sends messageses, when server is not run.
How can that be? What settings could i omit?
No such problems were detected during long using in wired net.

I even made special allowing rules in firewall, and after even turned it off completely, but the situation is still the same.

I don't know what to check or to do next.

I made the simplest hard-coded sample with this code and the result is the same(((

I get the "connected" word infinitely
//===========================================================

```
#include <iostream>
// stlplus
#include "portability.hpp"
#include "strings.hpp"

using namespace stlplus;
int INI_TCP_TIMEOUT = 10000000;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  stlplus::TCP_client tcpClient("192.168.173.1", 139, INI_TCP_TIMEOUT);

  if (false == tcpClient.initialised() ) 
  {
    std::cout << "client: retry";
    return 0;
  }

  if (false == tcpClient.connected()) 
  {
    std::cout << "client: retry";
    return 0;
  }

  while (true == tcpClient.connected()) 
  {
    std::cout << "connected; \n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Not sure that I treated the root of the problem, but who knows.
Here I write explanation in case somebody encounters the same problem or just can add something to make it more clear.

My aplication was organised next way:
there was a class in which i start the server in separate thread. I have two instances of that class,
so two servers were created approximately in the same time. And as I found one could not be initialised with the error message 10093 (either WSAStartup is not yet called or WSACleanup already called).

I tried to debug that inside ip_socket class but there were problems with multi-threading. So, i made a mutex that is locked just before server creations and unlocked immediately after.

After that all problems disappeared.